# implementation of mutex with single CPU instruction in ARM

Tags: assembly, synchronization, arm, embedded, mutex

I know that there are a few atomic instructions like test & set and compare & swap instruction which achieve the hardware implementation of a mutex. But I was curious to know is there a single instruction like Compare or swap alone on ARM which makes it possible to implement the mutex?

I think atleast two instructions (executed atomically) are needed to implement a mutex.

P.S. I was asked this in an interview after describing Compare and Swap. More of an optimization targetting on ARM. But I would like to know if its possible in other architectures also?

Comment: You could answer this yourself by a) simply looking through the instruction set, b) comparing existing ARM mutex implementations in any open-source OS. Whilst the answer [may change in future](http://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2014/12/02/the-armv8-a-architecture-and-its-ongoing-development), it's going to be _quite some time_ before any of that hits production.

Answer (score 1):

A mutex is too high a level mechanism to be implemented in a single instruction.  It requires information on which thread holds the lock, a count of the level of mutex nesting within the thread with the lock, and in a priority-based pre-emptive RTOS requires a priority inversion mechanism, which involves temporarily boosting the priority thread owning the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Even simple spinlocks tend to be a bad idea in a single operation. ARM used to have some simple "swap" instructions which atomically swap a value in registers with a value in memory, but they don't scale well to high frequency multi-core systems (as you effectively have to lock the bus to ensure the atomicity of the swap), so they got removed from the newer versions of the architecture and replaced with the multi-part load/store exclusive instructions.